# Error while assingning values explicitely in copy constructor

Tags: c++, string, class, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

here I'm trying to add two strings using overloaded operator+, but when assigned values explicitly it does not print the desirable output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class st{

char *p;
int len;

public:
    st(){len=0; p=0;}       //creates null string
    st(const char *s);      //creates string from arrays
    st(const st &s);        //copy constructor
    ~st(){delete p;}        //destructor

    //+ operator
    friend st operator + (const st &, const st &);

    //<= operator
    friend int operator <= (const st &, const st &);
    friend void show(const st);
  };

 st :: st(const char *s){
    len = strlen(s);
    p = new char[len+1];
    strcpy(p, s);
    //cout<<p<<"\n\n";
 }

st :: st(const st &s){
    len = s.len;
    p = new char[len+1];
    strcpy(p, s.p);
    //cout<<p;
 }

//overloading + operator
st operator + (const st &s, const st &t){
    st temp;
    temp.len = s.len + t.len;
    //cout<<temp.len<<" ";
    temp.p = new char[temp.len + 1];

    //cout<<s.p<<" ";
    strcpy(temp.p, s.p);
    //cout<<t.p<<" ";
    strcat(temp.p, t.p);
    //cout<<temp.p<<"\n\n";
    return(temp);
 }

  //overloading <= operator
int operator <= (const st &s, const st &t){
    int m = strlen(s.p);
    int n = strlen(t.p);

   if(m <= n)   return(1);
   else return(0);
}

void show(const st s){
    cout<<s.p;
}


int main(){
    st s1 = "New ";
    st s2 = "York";
    st s3 = "Delhi";
    //st string1=s1, string2=s2, string3=s1+s3;
    st string1, string2, string3;
    string1 = s1;
    string2 = s2;
    string3 = s3+s1;



    cout<<"\nstring1  =  "; show(string1);
    cout<<"\nstring2  =  "; show(string2);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"\nstring3  =  "; show(string3);
    cout<<"\n\n";

    if(string1 <= string2){
        show(string1);  cout<<" smaller than "; show(string2);
        cout<<endl;
    }else {
        show(string2);  cout<<" smaller than "; show(string2);
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As seen in the above code when i run it with

```
st string1=s1, string2=s2, string3=s1+s3;
```

it give the expected output, but when i try it with

```
st string1, string2, string3;
```

it prints some random string

Comment: You miss a very important part of [the rule of three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_three).

Comment: @Error_loading Your design is  wrong. For example the copy constructor does not create a copy of the original object that was created using the default constructor. In this case the program will have undefined behavior.

Comment: @Error_loading Take into accopunt that the parameter of the function  friend void show(const st); should be declared as reference friend void show(const st &);.

Comment: @Error_loading You should define two assignment operators. The first one is the copy assignment olperator and the second one is assignment operator that accepts a constant character pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `operator =` . Thus a default implementation is used which copies every field from the right hand side object to the left hand side object. This produces a copy of buffer pointer `p` in the left hand side object, i.e. two pointers point to the same buffer. No doubts it leads to an undefined behavior. You need to define `operator =` (or several overloaded operators if you wish).

Note that `st s1 = "New"` features a constructor as it's an initialization. In contrast, `string1 = s1` employs `operator = (const st&)`.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the default constructor should be defined at least like

```
st() : p( new char[1] ), len( 0 )
{
    *p = '\0';    
}
```

Otherwise using an object created with the default constructor as for example using it in the copy constructor or in the `operator +` will result in undefined behaviour.

The destructor shall be defined like

```
~st(){ delete []p; }
```

The function `show` should be declared at least like

```
friend void show(const st &);
```

or the follwoing way

```
friend std::ostream & show( const st &, std::ostream & = std::cout );
```

Or you could define a friend operator like

```
friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &, const st & );
```

As for your problem described in the question then you have to declare the copy assignment operator at least like

```
st & operator =( const st & );
```

And it is desirable to declare also the following assignment operator

```
std & operator =( const char * );
```